# Approximating a rational number in a subset of Q defined by limited prime factors

Tags: approximation, nonlinear-optimization, rational-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm wondering if there is an efficient (or good enough for small numbers) algorithm for the following problem:

Suppose I have a rational number in the form of its prime factorization:

$k = p_0^{x_0}p_1^{x_1}...p_n^{x_n}$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$

In regards to a subset $L \subset \mathbb{Q}$ defined by all numbers of the form

$k' = p_0^{x_0}p_1^{x_1}...p_m^{x_m}$ for a fixed $m$

find for any $k \in \mathbb{Q}$ a number $k' \in L$ so that $|k-k'|$ is minimized.

It can be assumed that $k$ is already given in the above form and does not need to be factorized first.

Comment: Based on the theory of continued fractions applied to $\log_2 3$ I'd expect $\{ 2^a 3^b \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ to already be dense in $\mathbb{R}^+$.  So already for $m=1$, there is no minimum and it can get arbitrary close to 0.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Since $\log_2 3$ is irrational, the fractional parts of multiples of $\log_2 3$ are dense in $[0,1]$, and therefore $2^a 3^b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ are dense in $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. I had not considered the possibility that the minimum might actually not exist. Can you elaborate or point to a resource that explains this a bit further? For my use case it also would be enough if $|k-k'|$ is smaller than some fixed number. Maybe I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: You have $k \in \Bbb Q$, but $L$ is restricted to positive numbers. Thus for $k \ge 0$, you can get $k'$ as close as you like (note that both Daniel and Robert discuss $\Bbb R^+$). If $k < 0$, then all $k' \in L$ will be $> |k|$ away from it. (I assume you either meant $k \in \Bbb Q^+$, or for $L$ to include both positives and negatives, but that is not what you currently have.)